# How to pass Id to Jquery statement - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass the EmployeeId of the row I click to the jQuery statement, but I get `null` everytime.
I would appreciate to know what am I doing wrong.

**Checkout my below Code :**

Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm" }))
{

    <table class="table">
        -- headers
      

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {


            <tr>


                <td> <button class="btn btn-success" id="BtnId" onclick="Update(@item.EmployeeId)"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></button> </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDeleted)
                </td>
               
            </tr>

      
        }
 </table>
}

    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var Update = function (EmployeeId) {
    
             
    
                $("#BtnId").on('click', function () {
                    var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();
                   
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Employee/Index?EmployeeId="+EmployeeId,
                        data:myformdata,
                        success: function () {
    
                        }
                    });
    
                   
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Employee Controller

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    EmployeeModule EM = new EmployeeModule();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(EM.List());
    }

   
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
       
      

        bool a = EM.ExecuteSP(id);

        return View(EM.List());

    }

}
```

Given an ID,the ExecuteSP method sets the column IsDelete to 2 . But as I said I just get a `null` ID everytime.

Answer (score 0):

In controller, You are expecting `id` name, So you need rename from `EmployeeId` to `id` like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           var Update = function (EmployeeId) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Employee/Index",
                        data: {id: EmployeeId},
                        success: function () {

                        }
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I keep getting a null  id

Comment: Did you debug with `data: {id: 123},`?

Comment: You debug and `id` still null ?

Comment: Yes. I'm still getting a null id.

Comment: How about `url: "Employee/Index?id="+EmployeeId` ?

Comment: I am still getting a null

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute in each page should be unique, hence using `#BtnId` is incorrect because ID is repeating. Add BtnId to the class attribute and add `EmployeeId` to `data-id` attribute instead. See the code below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
      <td>
         <button class="btn btn-success BtnId" data-id="@item.EmployeeId"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i></button>
       </td>
       <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsDeleted)
       </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Then in your script, it's better to bind the event to the button; Use `$(this).data("id")` and assign it to the variable EmployeeId which we will use in ajax.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   var EmployeeId = $(this).data("id");

   $(document).click(".BtnId",function(){
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Employee/Index",
         data: {id: EmployeeId},
         success: function () {

         }
      });
   });
```

Comment: I'm still geting a null Id

Comment: @Drey will you include a screenshot of the rendered html code. Right click >  Inspect Element